# БАД или бад?

Tags: аббревиатуры, прописная-строчная

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно писать аббревиатуру "бад" (биологически-активные добавки): строчными или прописными буквами?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не видел, чтобы где-то нормировалось. 
Но вообще-то из общих соображений - пока еще БАД. Не достигло того уровня, когда аббревиатура становится именем нарицательным (типа вуз).
Дефис, кстати, в "биологически активных" не нужен. Написание - раздельное.